# Reading Int from file in Java

Tags: java

Im trying to read from a text file certain numbers. It was working a few days ago and now suddenly its not reading the numbers after certain words. Here are my java functions for write and read. NOTE THIS IS USED IN A JSP:

```
    public void writeToFile() {


    try {
    File aFile = new File(nameOfFile + "MAIN" + ".txt");
    aFile.createNewFile();
    PrintWriter writeTo = new PrintWriter(aFile);


    writeTo.print("Matrix 1" + "\nRows: " + row1 + "\n");
    writeTo.print("Columns: " + column1 + "\n");
    writeTo.println("Method used: " + operationName);

    if("DotProduct".equals(operationName))
        writeTo.println("Vector: " + vectorRow1);

    writeTo.println();
    for(int i = 0; i < getRow1(); i++) {
        int counter = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < getCol1(); j++, counter++) 
            writeTo.print(matrixToFile[i][j] + "\t");
        if(counter == getCol1()) {
        writeTo.print("\n");    
        }
    } 
       writeTo.close();

    File aFile2 = new File(nameOfFile + "SECOND.txt");
    aFile2.createNewFile();
    writeTo = new PrintWriter(aFile2);
    writeTo.print("Matrix 2" + "\nRows: " + row2 + "\n");
    writeTo.print("Columns: " + column2 + "\n");

    if("DotProduct".equals(operationName))
        writeTo.println("Vector: " + vectorCol2);

    writeTo.println();
    for(int i = 0; i < getRow2(); i++) {
        int counter = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < getCol2(); j++, counter++) 
            writeTo.print(matrix2ToFile[i][j] + "\t");
        if(counter == getCol2()) {
        writeTo.print("\n");    
        }       
    } 
    writeTo.close();


    File aFile3 = new File(nameOfFile + "RESULT.txt");
    aFile3.createNewFile();
    writeTo = new PrintWriter(aFile3);
    writeTo.print("Result" + "\nRows: " + row3 + "\n");
    writeTo.print("Columns: " + column3 + "\n");
    writeTo.println();

    if("DotProduct".equals(operationName))
        writeTo.println("Result:" + resultVector);

    else {
    for(int i = 0; i < getRow3(); i++) {
        int counter = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < getCol3(); j++, counter++) 
            writeTo.print(result[i][j] + "\t");
            if(counter == getCol3()) {
            writeTo.print("\n");    
            }       
        }

    }
    writeTo.close();

    nameOfFile = "/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/Matrices/WEB-INF/MatrixData/";

    errors.put("dataStored", "Your results have been stored!");

    } catch(IOException ex) {

    System.out.printf("Error!");

    }

}
```

This is the read file:

```
 public void readFromFile(String resultOrNot, String fileName) {

    nameOfFile = "/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/Matrices/WEB-INF/MatrixData/";
    workMe = fileName;

    try {

    Scanner readFile = new Scanner(new File(nameOfFile + workMe));
    readFile.useDelimiter("Rows: ");

    while(readFile.hasNextInt()) {
        stringRow = readFile.next();

    }
    setRow1VIAString(stringRow);

    readFile.useDelimiter("Columns: ");

    while(readFile.hasNextInt()) {
        stringCol = readFile.next();

    }
    setColumn1VIAString(stringCol);

    readFile.useDelimiter("Method used: ");
    while(readFile.hasNext()) {
        operationName = readFile.next();
    }


    readFile.useDelimiter("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < row1 || readFile.hasNextDouble(); i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < column1; j++)
            matrix1[i][j] = readFile.nextDouble();

    readFile.close();



    workMe = workMe.replace("MAIN", "SECOND");
    readFile = new Scanner(new File(nameOfFile + workMe));
    readFile.useDelimiter("Rows: ");

    while(readFile.hasNextInt()) {
        stringRow = readFile.next();

    }
    setRow2VIAString(stringRow);

    readFile.useDelimiter("Columns: ");

    while(readFile.hasNextInt()) {
        stringCol = readFile.next();

    }
    setColumn2VIAString(stringCol);

    readFile.useDelimiter("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < row1 || readFile.hasNextDouble(); i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < column1; j++)
            matrix1[i][j] = readFile.nextDouble();

    readFile.close();

    if("giveMeResult".equals(resultOrNot)) {

    workMe = workMe.replace("SECOND", "RESULT");
    readFile = new Scanner(new File(nameOfFile + workMe));
    readFile.useDelimiter("Rows: ");

    while(readFile.hasNextInt()) {
        stringRow = readFile.next();

    }
    setRow3VIAString(stringRow);

    readFile.useDelimiter("Columns: ");

    while(readFile.hasNextInt()) {
        stringCol = readFile.next();

    }
    setColumn3VIAString(stringCol);

    readFile.useDelimiter("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < row3 || readFile.hasNextDouble(); i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < column3; j++)
            matrix1[i][j] = readFile.nextDouble();

    }




    } catch(IOException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }




}
```

The converting function:

```
    public void setRow1VIAString(String aRow) {

     row1 = Integer.parseInt(aRow);
 }
```

And this is the error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
matrixcalculator.MatrixCalculator.setRow1VIAString(MatrixCalculator.java:171)
matrixcalculator.MatrixCalculator.readFromFile(MatrixCalculator.java:728)
org.apache.jsp.choosing_jsp._jspService(choosing_jsp.java:84)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

I know it means that the string trying to me parse is null, what I dont understand is why is it null now? Its been working alright and now suddenly its doing this. Im aware of the whitespaces but I got them counted so that there wont be any problems.

Comment: Don't embed Java code in JSPs (scriptlets), and don't hard-code paths when you should be using classpath resources. This code will be a headache to debug precisely because it's impossible to separate out from the JSP.

Comment: I only use scriplets to call the functions. The whole reading, writing, is done in a Java class. And hard-code paths? Explain this please.

Comment: Looks like the value you're passing into `setRow1VIAString()` in `readFromFile()` on line 728 is null.  Presumably, you're never actually entering your `while` loop and setting `stringRow`.

Comment: Why wouldn't it enter the loop? The delimeter is literally the same in the text file. Even with the white space. Example of how it looks is Rows: 3